# TMSiBr and Oxalylchloride for ester cleavage

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am wondering what is the advantage of using TMSiBr do perform an ester cleavage in comparison to perform chlorination first for example with oxalylchloride or thionylchloride and than add water?

Comment: Oxalyl chloride to cleave an ester, are you sure about this reaction? Or Thionyl chloride?

Comment: TMSBr may be for specific esters. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple references: https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/slct.201900120 https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1747519819898142 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403915000763 As far as I understand TMSBr is more "soft". And oxalylchloride is only working with specific esters. More interesting for me are phosphonic acid esters in general.

Comment: The ester/ether cleavage with oxalyl chloride is with p-methoxybenzyl esters and ethers, an SN1 process. A special case and likely not general.

Comment: I have used TMSiI extensively for cleaving phosphonic esters